How to introduce a linear optical path difference (OPD) across a plane wave?
I'm working on a version of coherance scanning interferometry (CSI) - very similar optically to a Michelson interferometer with a sample and reference beam combined to produce an interferance pattern - and in my setup would like to introduce a linear optical path difference across one spatial dimension (x) in my reference beam.
The illumination would be a light emitting diode (LED) with a full width half maximum (FWHM) of ~25nm. With high spatial coherence (that I would like to conserve) but low temporal coherance.
Is there a way to do this? I can only think to use a stepped reference mirror - but these can get very expensive and I'm sure there is a better way.
Essentially the question boils down to: how do you introduce an optical path difference in x to a low (temporal) coherence plane wave travelling in z, while maintaining the spatial coherence? Is this possible?

Image adapted from Hugens Optics, Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMeRAg61_Wc
Thanks in advance :)

Consider to spell out acronyms.

Choose a plane tilted slightly with respect to the beam and you have a slightly longer path at one edge. One way to do this is with wedge prisms.

Perhaps I was ambiguous with the term coherence (question edited for clarity). Wouldn't a prism or grating change the temporal coherence?

I made a guess that you wanted to introduce a phase shift of < $2\pi$ across the beam and the temporal coherence length was longer than a wavelength. A pair of wedge prisms can make a window with parallel sides. This would delay the whole wavefront by the same amount and leave temporal coherence intact. If you twist one slightly, it forms a window with almost parallel sides. This delays one side of the beam slightly more than the other. The angle of a single wedge is only a few degrees.
